How can I fix "InvalidTableReference" error
When building my Substrate runtime, I'm encountering the following error:
(/Users/user/Documents/develop/repo/renkei/core/runtime)
error: failed to run custom build command for `renkei-runtime v0.0.1 (/Users/user/Documents/develop/repo/renkei/core/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/user/Documents/develop/repo/renkei/core/target/debug/build/renkei-runtime-feb543afbdcd5da9/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: env -u CARGO_ENCODED_RUSTFLAGS -u CARGO_TARGET_DIR RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=mvp -C target-feature=-sign-ext -C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/user/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-10-27-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/user/Documents/develop/repo/renkei/core/target/debug/wbuild/renkei-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.84.0-nightly (9b18a122f 2024-10-26)

  Failed to deserialize `/Users/user/Documents/develop/repo/renkei/core/target/debug/wbuild/renkei-runtime/renkei_runtime.wasm`: InvalidTableReference(128)

  --- stderr
      Finished `release` profile [optimized] target(s) in 0.23s

Environment

OS: macOS (Apple Silicon)
Rust version: nightly-2024-10-27
Substrate version: release-v1.2.0

How can I resolve this issue??


https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/releases/tag/polkadot-v1.2.0

Your Substrate version is quite old, try:
Rust Stable: rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)
Rust Nightly: rustc 1.71.0-nightly (8b4b20836 2023-05-22)

